# when I call a function inside context I get "namefunction" is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am using ReactJS (the latest version 16.8.6)
 I have two files:

> "context.js" file containing a static list of contacts and an exported Provider.
>   "addcontact.js" file which is a form to add a contact to this list inside the context.

I want just to verify that the function is called but when I fill the inputs and submit the form I had this exception
`addcontact is not a function at AddContact.onsubmit`

instead of 
`<form onSubmit={this.onsubmit.bind(this,addcontact)}>`

i add onClick event inside input like this
`<input type="submit" value="add contact" onClick={this.onsubmit.bind(this,addcontact)} />`

**context.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' 

const Context = React.createContext();

 export  class Provider extends Component {


state= { 

    contacts : [ {  
        id : 1,
        name : ' john ' ,
        email : ' jhon@gmail.com',
        phone : ' 1111111111 '
     },
     {  
      id : 2,
      name : ' peter ' ,
      email : ' peter@gmail.com',
      phone : ' 2222222222 '
   },
   {  
      id : 3,
      name : ' lisa ' ,
      email : ' lisa@gmail.com',
      phone : ' 3333333333 '

   }   ]    ,

   deletecontact : id => this.setState({
     contacts :  this.state.contacts.filter( c => 
        c.id !== id  )

   }, 
 )
,
addcontact : () => {

    console.log('success'); }  }


render() {

    return (

    <Context.Provider value={this.state} >
        {this.props.children}
    </Context.Provider> 
    )
}

 }
 export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

**AddContact.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'

 import {Consumer} from '../../context'

 import uuid from 'uuid'



 export class AddContact extends Component {

 state = {
 name :'',
 email:'',
 phone:''
 }

 changecontact = (e) => {

 this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value } );

 }


 onsubmit = (addcontact,e) => {

 e.preventDefault();

 const {name ,email,phone } = this.state;



 addcontact()

 }


render() {

const {name , email , phone } = this.state;

    return (

 <Consumer>


 {value => {

 const addcontact = value;

 return (

 <div className="card mb-3">

 <div className="card-header">

 Add Contact

 <div className="card-body">

 <form onSubmit={this.onsubmit.bind(this,addcontact)}>

 <div className="form-group">

 <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>

 <input type="text"
        name="name"
        className="form-control form-control-lg"
        placeholder="Enter Name ..." 
        value={name}
        onChange={this.changecontact}
        >


 </input>

 </div>


 <div className="form-group">

 <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>

 <input type="email" 
 name="email"
 className="form-control form-control-lg"
 placeholder="Enter Email ..."
 value={email} 
 onChange={this.changecontact} >


 </input>

 </div>


<div className="form-group">

<label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>

<input type="text"

 name="phone"
 className="form-control form-control-lg"
 placeholder="Enter Phone ..."
 value={phone}
 onChange={this.changecontact} >


 </input>

 </div>  
 <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" className="btn btn-block btn-          
 light" />

 </form>

 </div>


 </div> 


 </div>

 )
 }}




 </Consumer>


  )


      }

 }

 `
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `this` before your `addcontact` method in your function.

```
<form onSubmit={this.onsubmit.bind(this, this.addcontact)}>
```

Comment: still the same exception
addcontact is not a function

Comment: Ok, please format your code examples and preferably add a working example

Comment: It works successfully in CODESANDBOX 
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-grass-3wzmt
but l get this exception locally , what 's going wrong about you
i 'm using Google Chrome